# JS function looping double as expected

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, console.log

This is Javascript code for some quiz i am making.
In my case table.length = 2, and function is repeating 2 times with parameter for first table and second.

But why command shows 4 times in console?

```
console.log("Hello");
```

.

```
function start(){
    var brojac =0;
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for (i =0; i<table.length ; i++){
        jednoPitanje(i);
        brojac += parseInt(jednoPitanje(i))

    }
    console.log("Sakupili ste ukupno " + brojac + " bodova");
}

function jednoPitanje(x) {
    var odgovori ="";
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var tableN = table[x];
    var input = tableN.getElementsByTagName("input")
    var brojInputa = tableN.getElementsByTagName("input").length;

    //Uzima bodove,kategoriju i index tocnih odgovora
    var bodovi =tableN.classList[2];
    var kategorija =tableN.classList[1];
    var tocni = tableN.classList[0];

    console.log("Hello");

    //Iteracija kroz sve checkboxsove u tablici
    for (j =0; j<brojInputa ; j++){
        if(input[j].checked==true){
            odgovori += tableN.getElementsByTagName("input")[j].value;
        }
    }
    if(odgovori == tocni){      
    }
    else{bodovi = 0;}

    return bodovi;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me it helps when code is properly indented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `console.log("Hello");` in the function `jednoPitanje()`. You call this function twice inside your loop:

```
 jednoPitanje(i);  // <-- this cause console.log() to run
 brojac += parseInt(jednoPitanje(i)) // <-- this also causes the console.log()
```

and since your loop runs twice it prints four times.

It's not immediately clear if you *need* that function to run twice, but if you don't, you can just remove the first call:

```
for (i =0; i<table.length ; i++){
    brojac += parseInt(jednoPitanje(i))
}
```

or if you prefer the extra clarity:

```
for (i =0; i<table.length ; i++){
    var bodovi = jednoPitanje(i);
    brojac += parseInt(bodovi)
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need ! tanks